# What method is used to sort this number in the Java program?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have input

```
1 31 22 32 11 13 12
```

then I want to have results like this

```
1
11
31
12
22
32
13
```

What sort of method should I use?
thank you

Comment: You should first analyze the problem and think about how those are ordered. Once you know this, you'll be able to understand what the sorting algorithm should do to produce the wanted result.

Comment: Can you explain what the sort criterion is here? I cannot understand it from the example alone. (It looks like it is sorted numerically according to the number read backwards, but how can we know?)

Comment: the program sort numbers by the last digit

Comment: How does it break ties (same last digit)? Keep original order? Use next digit? Unspecified?

Comment: @AdityaNanda What is the expected output for having the value 311 in the list as well?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sort` for this (Java 8), with a slightly modified comparator:

```
yourList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(number -> number % 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is sorting by last digit, then by numeral value.

You could do:

```
    Comparator<Integer> c = (a, b) -> {
        int n = Integer.compare(a % 10, b % 10);
        if (n != 0) {
            return n;
        }
        return Integer.compare(a, b);
    };
    Stream.of(1, 31, 22, 32, 11, 13, 12).sorted(c).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to run a sort by numerical value such as quicksort and then a stable sort on on the last digit of the numbers (%10) such as insertion sort;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1,31,22,32,11,13,12};
        sort(numbers,0,numbers.length-1);
        sort(numbers);
        for(int i : numbers) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    static int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {
        int pivot = arr[high];
        int i = (low-1);
        for (int j=low; j<high; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] <= pivot)
            {
                i++;

                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        int temp = arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = arr[high];
        arr[high] = temp;

        return i+1;
    }

    static void sort(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {
        if (low < high)
        {

            int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

            sort(arr, low, pi-1);
            sort(arr, pi+1, high);
        }
    }
    static void sort(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i=1; i<n; ++i)
        {
            int key = arr[i];
            int j = i-1;

            /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
               greater than key, to one position ahead
               of their current position */
            while (j>=0 && arr[j]%10 > key%10)
            {
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                j = j-1;
            }
            arr[j+1] = key;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorting algorithms pinched from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired ordering for arbitrary length positive integers using the following `compare` method:

```
public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2)
{
  for(int c; i1 != 0 && i2 != 0; i1/=10, i2/=10)
  {
    if((c = Integer.compare(i1 % 10, i2 % 10)) != 0) 
      return c;
  }
  return Integer.compare(i1, i2);
}
```

Interestingly, this is a lexicographic ordering of the reversed string representation of each number, so you could do:

```
String[] s = "1 31 22 32 11 13 12".split(" ");
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) s[i] = new StringBuilder(s[i]).reverse().toString();
Arrays.sort(s);
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) s[i] = new StringBuilder(s[i]).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Output:

```
[1, 11, 31, 12, 22, 32, 13]
```

BTW, how crazy is it that there's no simple built-in method for returning the reverse of a `String` in Java?